# Columns value comparison in Spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which contains huge number of records. In that DF a record can be repeated multiple times and every time when it got updated the last updated field will have the date on which the record modified.

We have a group of columns on which we want to compare the rows of similar ids. During this comparison we want to capture what are the fields/columns has changed from previous record to current record and capture that in a "updated_columns" column of the updated record. Compare this second record to third record and identify the updated columns and capture that in "updated_columns"  field of third record, continue the same till the last record of that id and do the same thing for each and every id which has more than one entry.

Initially we grouped the columns and created a hash out of that group of columns and compare against hash values of next row,this way it is helping me to identify records which has updates, but want the columns which got updated.

Here I am sharing some data, which is expected outcome and that is how the final data should like look post adding updated columns (here I can say, use columns Col1, Col2, Col3, col4 and Col5 for comparison between two rows):

[image]

Want to do this in a efficient way. Any one tried some thing like this.

Looking for a help!

~Krish.

Comment: A graphical representation always helps!

Comment: I have updated the question with example, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/WindowSpec.html) can be used.

The idea is to group the data by *ID*, sort it by *LAST-UPDATED*, copy the values of the previous row (if it exists) into the current row and then compare the copied data with the current values.

```scala
val data = ... //the dataframe has the columns ID,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,LAST_UPDATED,IS_DELETED

val fieldNames = data.schema.fieldNames.dropRight(1) //1
val columns = fieldNames.map(f => col(f))
val windowspec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("LAST_UPDATED") //2
def compareArrayUdf() = ... //3

val result = data
  .withColumn("cur", array(columns: _*)) //4
  .withColumn("prev", lag($"cur", 1).over(windowspec)) //5
  .withColumn("updated_columns", compareArrayUdf()($"cur", $"prev")) //6
  .drop("cur", "prev") //7
  .orderBy("LAST_UPDATED")
```

Remarks:

1. create a list of all fields to compare. All fields but the last one (*LAST-UPDATED*) are used
2. create a window that is partitioned by *ID* and each partition is sorted by *LAST-UPDATED*
3. create a udf that compares two arrays and maps the discovered differences to the field names, code see below
4. create a new column that contains all values that should be compared
5. create a new column that contains all values of the *previous* row (by using the [lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lag-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-int-)-function) that should be compared. The previous row is the row with the same *ID* and the biggest *LAST-UPDATED* that is smaller than the current one. This field can be null
6. compare the two new columns and put the result into *updated-columns*
7. drop the two intermediate columns created in step 3 and 4

The *compareArraysUdf* is

```scala
def compareArray(cur: mutable.WrappedArray[String], prev: mutable.WrappedArray[String]): String = {
  if (prev == null || cur == null) return ""
  val res = new StringBuilder
  for (i <- cur.indices) {
    if (!cur(i).contentEquals(prev(i))) {
      if (res.nonEmpty) res.append(",")
      res.append(fieldNames(i))
    }
  }
  res.toString()
}
def compareArrayUdf() = udf[String, mutable.WrappedArray[String], mutable.WrappedArray[String]](compareArray)
```

Comment: Even we are having a very similar use case, but our volume is very is huge and is 150 Million records, when I do Window.partitionBy("ID"), it is creating too many partitions and is failing. Is there a way to by pass through this, or am I doing some thing wrong in my case? Looking forward for some help!

Answer (score 0):

You can join your DataFrame or DataSet to itself, joining the rows where the id is the same in both rows and where the version of the left row is `i` and the version of the right row is `i+1`. Here's an example

```
case class T(id: String, version: Int, data: String)

val data = Seq(T("1", 1, "d1-1"), T("1", 2, "d1-2"), T("2", 1, "d2-1"), T("2", 2, "d2-2"), T("2", 3, "d2-3"), T("3", 1, "d3-1"))
data: Seq[T] = List(T(1,1,d1-1), T(1,2,d1-2), T(2,1,d2-1), T(2,2,d2-2), T(2,3,d2-3), T(3,1,d3-1))

val ds = data.toDS

val joined = ds.as("ds1").join(ds.as("ds2"), $"ds1.id" === $"ds2.id" && (($"ds1.version"+1) === $"ds2.version"))
```

And then you can reference the columns in the new DataFrame/DataSet like `$"ds1.data` and `$"ds2.data` etc.

To find the rows where the data changed from one version to another, you can do

```
joined.filter($"ds1.data" !== $"ds2.data")
```

Comment: This is a self join, but with this, how can we get to know the list of columns for which the values got changed from the previous record to current record? Am I missing any thing here?

Comment: I updated the answer and showed an example of how you can compare the values of one row to the values of the other row. Hopefully that should give you an idea

Comment: Thanks for sharing your view, I have already worked out on this, but this requires comparing the column by column and then I can capture what column got updated and populate that updated columns. I am looking for some efficient way of comparing the fields and deriving the field names for which the data got updated and then i can populate that in updated columns.